# PHP create HTML table with a while loop from query sql

Tags: php, sql-server, while-loop, html-table

I have to do a query to get the total of product filtred by payment type

My table:

```
product_id, paymentType     price
87               E          1
87               E          3
87               C          5
87               V          30
100              C          1
359              E          12
359              C          32
```

My query:

```
$query = select count(*) as qte, paymentType as PT, product_id as PID, sum(price) as PR from mytable 
        group by product_id, paymentType 
        order by product_id
```

the result of the query is :

```
  product_id   paymentType  qte        price
    87         E             2           4
    87         C             1           5
    87         V             1           30
    100        C             1           1
    359        E             1           12
    359        C             1           32
```

I need to create table on php as  :

```
$output .= '<table  border="1" >';
$output .= '<thead>';
    $output .= '<tr>';
        $output .= '<th><div style="width:150px" >product</div></th>';
        $output .= '<th>paymentType E</th>';
        $output .= '<th>Qte E</th>';
        $output .= '<th>total price E</th>';
        $output .= '<th>paymentType C </th>';
        $output .= '<th>Qte C</th>';
        $output .= '<th>total price C</th>';
        $output .= '<th>paymentType v </th>';
        $output .= '<th>Qte V</th>';
        $output .= '<th>total price V</th>';
    $output .= '</tr>';
$output .= '</thead>';
$output .= '<tbody>';

if ($row){


        $old_product_id = -1;  

        do {
                // ID du produit 
                $product_id = $row->PID;

            /*  switch($row->PT){
                    case 'E': {
                         $output .= ' <td  class="center"  >'.$row->PT.'</td>';
                         $output .= ' <td class="center"  >'.$row->qte.' </td>';
                         $output .= ' <td class="center"  >'.$row->PR.'</td>';
                         break;
                    }
                    case 'C: {
                         $output .= ' <td  class="center"  >'.$row->PT.'</td>';
                         $output .= ' <td class="center"  >'.$row->qte.' </td>';
                         $output .= ' <td class="center"  >'.$row->PR.'</td>';
                             break;
                    }
                    case 'V': {
                         $output .= ' <td  class="center"  >'.$row->PT.'</td>';
                         $output .= ' <td class="center"  >'.$row->qte.' </td>';
                         $output .= ' <td class="center"  >'.$row->PR.'</td>';
                         break;
                    }
                }
                */

                 if ($old_product_id == $product_id){
                     $output .= '<tr>';                
                         $output .= ' <td style="width:200px;">'.$row->PID.'</td>';
                         // payment type  E
                         $output .= ' <td  class="center"  >'.$row->PT.'</td>';
                         $output .= ' <td class="center"  >'.$row->qte.' </td>';
                         $output .= ' <td class="center"  >'.$row->PR.'</td>';
                         // payment type C
                         $output .= ' <td  class="center"  >'.$row->PT.'</td>';
                         $output .= ' <td class="center"  >'.$row->qte.' </td>';
                         $output .= ' <td class="center"  >'.$row->PR.'</td>';
                        // payment type V
                        $output .= ' <td  class="center"  >'.$row->PT.'</td>';
                         $output .= ' <td class="center"  >'.$row->qte.' </td>';
                         $output .= ' <td class="center"  >'.$row->PR.'</td>';
                     $output .= '</tr>';

                 }else{

                 }

                 $old_product_id = $product_id;



           }while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result));

            $output .= '</tr>';
            $output .= '</tbody>';
            $output .= '</table>';


            $this->db->free();

            echo  $output;  

}else {
    echo 'no data found ';
}
```

Any solution to get this worK ? thanks if advance :)

my script doesn't work , I can't show the row for the same product with different payment type in the same row

Comment: Could you add some more code to the question?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: my script doesn't work , I can't show the row for the same product with different payment type in the same row

Comment: for example for the product with id = 87 the script add 3 rows but in fact it would add one row with different payment type

Answer (score 1):

I created a script that would do the headers for you aswell:

**Get data:**

```
<?php 

require('connect.php'); 

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM BLAH";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

## Get Results ##

$data = array(); ## Variable to hold data.

while (($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

sqlsrv_close($conn);

?>
```

**Display data:**

```
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <?php
                  foreach(array_keys($data[0]) as $key) {
                    echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
                  }
                ?>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
                foreach($data as $key) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                      foreach($key as $vals) {
                        echo "<td>" . $vals . "</td>";
                      }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
              ?>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: as I said, the script should show  one row for the same product ( eg product with id = 87) , you can see example in the main post

Comment: Well your question isn't very clear, your title suggests you want an easy way to loop through SQL results. But what it seems is you actually want a way to `PIVOT` your data. It would be easier looking into `PIVOT` in SQL Server: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: i think the easiest way to loop is using php , if it's the same product we dont have to create a new row  else we create a new row

Comment: You're designing a cursor in PHP to run through a set of data. SQL is set based anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function which helps you to create a table not thinking about design. Just pass the SQL.

Call As like this -

```
$fieldname=array("name","Roll");
$query = "Select name,roll from Student";
create_table($query,$fieldname,$id='mytable');


function create_table($query,$fieldname,$id='mytable'){
print' <table id="'.$id.'" class="table table-striped">';
print'<tr>';
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($fieldname);$i++){
print'<th>'.$fieldname[$i].'</th>';
}
print'</tr>';


$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){

print ' <tr>';

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($row)/2;$i++){
print'<td>'.$row[$i].'</td>';
}

print' </tr>';

}

print'</table>';}
```